# Matching Records With Missing Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 5 columns.

I don't want an INSERT to occur if any 3 out of the 5 columns matched any existing record i.e. the other 2 columns had differing or missing values.

Is this possible? If so, how?

I'm using SQL Server

Comment: You could use an `EXISTS`, but if you have a lot of colums then such operations are going to start to get expensive. Unfortunately you don't have many options in regards to the expense. Having to check the value of every column is a costly operation.

Comment: Just write a before insert trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, counting the matches is one possible approach:

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
    Column1 varchar(10),   
    Column2 varchar(10),   
    Column3 varchar(10),   
    Column4 varchar(10),   
    Column5 varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO #Data 
   (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5)
VALUES
    ('Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4', 'Value5'),
    ('alue1',  'Value2', 'Value3', 'alue4',  'Value'),
    ('alue1',  'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4', 'Value5'),
    ('alue1',  'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4', 'Value5'),
    ('Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4', 'Value5')
```

Statement:

```
-- New values
DECLARE @value1 varchar(10)
DECLARE @value2 varchar(10)
DECLARE @value3 varchar(10)
DECLARE @value4 varchar(10)
DECLARE @value5 varchar(10)
SET @value1 = 'Value1'
SET @value2 = 'Value2'
SET @value3 = 'Value3'
SET @value4 = 'Value4'
SET @value5 = 'Value5'

-- Statement
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM #Data
    WHERE (
        CASE WHEN Column1 = @value1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Column2 = @value2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Column3 = @value3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Column4 = @value4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Column5 = @value5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ) >= 3
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5)
VALUES
    (@Value1, @Value2, @Value3, @Value4, @Value5)
```